# Django/Testing: How do I populate the initial DB data when functional testing against staging server

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to run functional test for a Django webapp. The test is for a step in the middle of a process, so it requires the user to already have some data in the DB.

When I'm testing on my local PC, I use `LiveServerTestCase` to spin up the server and interact with it through Selenium, generating the data in the `setUp` function using model code from the concerned app.

When I'm testing against the staging server however, and I interact with it through Selenium on my local PC, the setUp code does nothing since it's running on my local PC.

My questions:
1) is it best practice to use model code to initialize a functional test (since it's supposed to be blackbox)?
2) how would I populate the DB when running against the staging server?